# How can I measure the execution time of a script?

Tags: javascript, timer

How would I measure the time it takes for a script to run from start to finish?

```
 start-timing
   //CODE
 end-timing
```

Comment: Remember, a grammatically correct title and relevant tags makes all the difference.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to measure time taken by a function to execute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/313893/how-to-measure-time-taken-by-a-function-to-execute)

Answer (score 53, accepted):

***EDIT**: in January 2011, this was the best available solution. Other solutions (such as `performance.now()` should be preferred now.*

```
var start = new Date();
    // CODE
var time = new Date() - start;
// time is the number of milliseconds it taken to execute the script
```

You may also want to wrap that in a function:

```
function time_my_script(script) {
    var start = new Date();
    script();
    return new Date() - start;
}

// call it like this:
time = time_my_script(function() {
    // CODE
});

// or just like this:
time = time_my_script(func);
```

If you are trying to profile your code, you may want to try the [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) extension, which includes a javascript profiler. It has a great user interface for profiling, but it also can be done programmatically with its [console api](http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Console_API#console.time.28name.29) :

```
console.time('timer1');
    // CODE
console.timeEnd('timer1'); // this prints times on the console

console.profile('profile1');
    // CODE
console.profileEnd('profile1'); // this prints usual profiling informations, per function, etc.
```

Comment: You don't need to call `getTime()`: using the `-` operator converts each `Date` object to its time value anyway. For example, `return new Date() - start;`

Comment: Amazes me how sometimes the solutions are sooooo simple and elegant! :-)

Comment: `performance.now()` should be preferred over `new Date()` - see other answer by Morteza Ziaeemehr.

Comment: @PierreArnaud please check the date before down voting (:

Comment: @arnaud576875 you are right - I added a note at the beginning of your answer to clearly indicate that the answer dates back to 01.2011. And that other solutions exist today.

Answer (score 11):

Use `performance.now()` instead of `new Date()`. This provides a more accurate and better result. See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/15641427/730000

Answer (score 2):

## Use the [User Timing api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/User_Timing_API)

For example: 
in the **beginning** of the JS file write: `performance.mark("start-script")`

at the **end** of the JS file write: `performance.mark("end-script")`

then you can measure it too:

`performance.measure("total-script-execution-time", "start-script", "end-script");`

This will give you the time it takes to run the entire script execution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick function to work like a stopwatch

```
var Timer = function(id){
  var self = this;
  self.id  = id;
  var _times = [];
  self.start = function(){
    var time = performance.now();
    console.log('[' + id + '] Start');
    _times.push(time);
  }
  self.lap = function(time){
    time = time ? time: performance.now();
    console.log('[' + id + '] Lap ' + time - _times[_times.length - 1]);
    _times.push(time);
  }
  self.stop = function(){
    var time = performance.now();
    if(_times.length > 1){
      self.lap(time);
    }
    console.log('[' + id + '] Stop ' + (time - _times[0]));
    _times = [];
  }
}
// called with
var timer = new Timer('process label');
timer.start(); // logs => '[process label] Start'
// ... code ...
timer.lap();   // logs => '[process label] Lap ' + lap_time
// ... code ...
timer.stop();  // logs => '[process label] Stop ' + start_stop_diff
```