# Using jsmeter for my asp.net applications

Tags: javascript, asp.net, performance

Is it possible to use jsmeter for analysis of performance of javascript on my own application?
I am not talking about .js files, I want to measure the performance of javascript on my asp.net application pages. 
Are there any other tools for same purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use build-in browser profiles. For example [Chrome profiler](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/06/12/javascript-profiling-chrome-developer-tools/) or [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/javascript/) for Firefox to measure the time of execution.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if there are any third party tools available but you can refer to answers here: [How to measure time taken by a function to execute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/313893/how-to-measure-time-taken-by-a-function-to-execute)

You will notice `console.time` and `console.timeEnd` can be used to easily measure performance of your js.