# How do you measure 3rd party ads load time using javascript?

Tags: javascript, performance, page-load-time

I have a *3<sup>rd</sup> party advertisement* block on my webpage. Using `javascript`, how do I measure the total time it takes to load, parse response and render the advertisement block?

I want to send this timing information back to my server to do reports.

Comment: Is the network tab of the chrome developer tools/firebug sufficient?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot rely solely on `javascript` to provide you with the solution you are after.
the biggest problem is the the difficulty in programatically figuring out when the events *load*, *parse* and *render* occur. The closest you can come is recording the time between sending the request and then periodically checking for content in the advertisement container.

Now, if you definitely know the exact template of content that the ad provider will return, you will need to use a script that will periodically check if all the items in the template have loaded and thus measure the time.

Another technique is to use `Ajax`. If you are able to load the provider's advertisement using `ajax`, you could always calculate the time it took using callbacks and then dynamically add the advert into the page. (also see: [How to measure time taken by a function to execute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/313893/how-to-measure-time-taken-by-a-function-to-execute))
To go beyond this, you will need the ad provider to provide you with an `api` or `callbacks` that you could hook into.

---

I would suggest taking a look at [Boomerang](https://github.com/lognormal/boomerang) as it helps to measure the performance of your website from your end user's point of view. Other than that, you are at the mercy of external tools like:

- Browser developer tools available in all major browsers. In Chrome use the *Network* or *Timelines* tab
- http://tools.pingdom.com/
- http://www.webpagetest.org/

Comment: I'd use LogNormal's version of Boomerang as it's @bluesmoon's baby- edited link for this