# Browser console and calculating multiple javascript execution time differences

Tags: javascript, performance, javascript-debugger

I can easily do this:

```
console.time('mytimer');
doSomeWork();
console.timeEnd('mytimer');
```

But is it possible to calculate time in multiple functions. I need to define the script's start time in a global variable. Then inside multiple functions I will write how many miliseconds passed since the start of the time. And write the name of the function Something like this:

```
console.time('mytimer');
doSomeWork() {
  // console.log(difference between now and "mytimer"s start time)
  // console.log(name of the function: doSomeWork())
};
doSomeWork2() {
  // console.log(difference between now and "mytimer"s start time)
  // console.log(name of the function: doSomeWork2())
};
doSomeWork3() {
  // console.log(difference between now and "mytimer"s start time)
  // console.log(name of the function: doSomeWork3())
};
console.timeEnd('mytimer');
```

I will use this in Chrome 26+ for debug issues so using browser dependent functions (for example: arguments.callee.name) is not a problem.

Edit: To clearize my problem.
This works:

```
console.time('myTimer1');
console.timeEnd('myTimer1');
```

This doesn't work:

```
console.time('myTimer2');
console.time('myTimer2');
```

Edit: Of course it is possible to write too much timers and check time of each of them. But I need to know elapsed time since the javascript code is started in each lap.

Comment: You have already answered your question, using a global variable and arguments.callee.name. What exactly you need as an answer then?

Comment: I couldn't get the time difference with console.time.

Comment: ISTM the profiler (“Profiles" tab) is made for this.

Comment: console.time('myTimer2');
console.timeEnd('myTimer2');
Did u meant this?

Comment: ```console.timeEnd``` stops the timer and I can't reach the "myTimer2" anymore.

Comment: @PointedEars Profiles tab is good for general behaviour. I need to examine specific points with this, and it's hard to select javascript parts from that.

Comment: What do you think of the answer posted?

Comment: Regarding to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/313893/how-to-measure-time-taken-by-a-function-to-execute) it is not recommended to use Date() for performance timings. So after some time if I can't find an answer with console.time, I will accept it :)

Answer (score 1):

If you need times on particular function, I guess you know that they can be achieved with argument to console.time() and console.timeEnd(). More info about it here https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console/ .

From my understanding of your question you need laps for benchmark analysis.

I have defined following methods which you can use to get lap times in milliseconds.

---

**Update** :  Using [performance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/now) api which is recommended API for such use cases.

```
console.lapStart = function(name){
     window[name] = window[name] || {};
     window[name].globalTimer = performance.now();
}
console.showLap = function(name){
     currTime = performance.now();
     var diff = currTime  - window[name].globalTimer;
     console.log(arguments.callee.name, diff);
}
console.lapEnd = function(name){
     currTime = performance.now();
     var diff = currTime  - window[name].globalTimer;
     console.log(arguments.callee.name, diff);
     delete window[name]
}
```

Note that this is rough code and should be run only in dev. Otherwise it might leave bad traces in global object and bad taste on your mouth.

Comment: Wow! A downvote for so old answer without a comment.

Comment: I asume the downvote is because of the usage of the performance intesive Date() function...

Comment: Updated answer to use [performace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/now) api.

Answer (score 1):

There is a solution which is a living standard. Seems like its already on chrome and major browsers and nodejs

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/timeLog

```
console.time("answer time");
alert("Click to continue");
console.timeLog("answer time");
alert("Do a bunch of other stuff...");
console.timeEnd("answer time");
The
```