# Javascript : log execution time of functions using a base-function?

Tags: javascript, function, prototype

I want to log the execution times of all my Javascript functions into a HTML5 local database (or use ajax to post the restults to the server), so I can find out which functions are the most time consuming and need to be tweaked.

I figured I should have some kind of 'base'-function that does this logging, on which I base all my other functions.

I know a little bit about prototype classes in Javascript, but obviously not enough. Are functions also some kind of objects that can be extended ?

Is it even possible to create this kind of base-function which starts a timer at the beginning of the function, and then *after* the extended function is finished then logs the execution time?

Comment: Function.prototype.something adds something to all functions. if you want added functionality for existing functions, you need to rewrite or wrap them. return arguments.callee.apply(this, arguments); works transparently and generically without "use strict" in effect.

Comment: No. Functions can be extended with methods via their prototype, but that won't help you to do logging when they are called.

Comment: You should use the built-in profiler of your devtools, instead of impacting the behavior of the functions by doing additional logging.

Comment: have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16759647/browser-console-and-calculating-multiple-javascript-execution-time-differences) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/313893/how-to-measure-time-taken-by-a-function-to-execute)