# Javascript: measure code execution time online

Tags: javascript, performance, performance-testing

I'm experiencing the need to test the performance differences of some variants of code (native/with plugins).

Is there an online service, like jsbin, jsfiddle for execution, where I can put the code in,
like

```
// BEGIN
var bla;
jQuery.map(bla, function(){});
// END
```

and get execution time?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

One option is

[jsperf.com](http://jsperf.com)

**OR**

```
//works in chrome and firefox
console.time("myCode"); // 'myCode' is the namespace
//execute your code here
console.timeEnd("myCode");
```

**OR**

```
var startTime = window.performance.now();
//execute your code here
console.log(window.performance.now() - startTime);
```

Comment: `window.performance.now()` should be used instead of `new Date()` – http://stackoverflow.com/a/21121773/1131963

Answer (score 8):

Using the 'User Timing API' is a modern way of doing this: 
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webperformance/usertiming/

Answer (score 1):

Below approaches I have found till now:-

**Approach 1:-**

```
let start = window.performance.now()
/// Your code goes here
let end = window.performance.now()
console.log(`Component Persing Time: ${end - start} ms`);
```

**Approach 2:-**

```
let start = Date.now()
/// Your code goes here
let end = Date.now()
console.log(`Component Persing Time: ${end - start} ms`);
```

**Approach 3:-**

```
console.time();
// Your code goes here
console.timeEnd();
```

***Any above approches you may proceed but got the same result. Happy coding. :)***

Answer (score 0):

```
var startTime = Date.now();

// code ...

console.log("Elapsed time (ms): " + (Date.now() - startTime));
```