# How do you measure google maps loading times

Tags: javascript, performance, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, performance-testing

I'm working on optimization a Google Maps with a lot of pins.  I want to see if what i'm doing has some impact but beside EndTime-StartTime in javascript i don;t know any other method.

Can you help me with some ideas ?

Comment: If you `console.log(EndTime-StartTime)`, does it not show up long time _before_ the browser has finished rendering all the markers?

Comment: yes it shows before, 1-2 second before

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in two ways:

1. By adding `startDate` and `endDate` before and after the Google map's initialize method.
2. This is pretty easy, you can simply open your dev tools and within **`network`** tab you can measure the *timeline of loading scripts.*

After some search I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1975103/1671639), which is about [**console.time**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console.time), *Starts a timer you can use to track how long an operation takes.*

[image]

Comment: Yes, but there is extreme difference in how fast and efficient each browser renders a google map with a lot of markers. How would you measure the time consumed and detect slow / perhaps optimiseable functions / operations in IE?

Comment: @davidkonrad Currently I can't check with my machine. Bit I remember IE too have an option "Network" to measure the elapsed time.

Answer (score 1):

May I suggest a different approach to this problem.  While instrumenting your code will certainly help identity problem areas, I think you already know the cause of your performance issues: the number of markers drawn on the map canvas.

I faced a similar situation, and had success using the [viewport management strategy](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/marker-clustering#viewportmarkermanagement) to optimize the performance of a large number of items on the map.  The basic theory is to handle the event the map's `bounds_changed` in tandem with the map's `idle` events.  You can easily check each marker to see if it is outside the current viewport using something like:

```
// anonymous function that sets only the markers inside the map's viewport
// as visible; all markers outside the active viewport are set as invisible
// to boost performance
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', function() {
   // wait until the pan/zoom has stopped before processing the viewport
   google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function() {
     var bounds = map.getBounds(); 

     for (var i = 0, length = markers.length; i < length; i++) {
       marker.setVisible(bounds.contains(marker.getPosition()));
     }
   });
});
```

In this example screenshot from Google, only a subset of markers would be visible inside the blue bounding box using this strategy:

[image: Example viewport]

Adapting this strategy will likely give you the biggest bang for your buck right away compared to instrumenting your existing code.

If this isn't enough, I recommend using a recursive asynchronous function to add your markers to the screen, like:

```
// the Bermuda triangle 
var coords = [
    new google.maps.LatLng(25.774252, -80.190262),
    new google.maps.LatLng(18.466465, -66.118292),
    new google.maps.LatLng(32.321384, -64.75737) 
];

// a variable to keep track of markers added to the map
var markers = [];

var addMarker = function addMarker() {
  var marker,
      position;

  if (coords.length === 0) {
    return;
  }

  // dequeue a coord from the queue of coords to process
  position = coords.unshift();

  // create a marker for the coord
  var marker = new google.maps.LatLng({
     position: position,
     visible: bounds.contains(position),
     map: map
  });

  // store the reference to the new marker
  markers.push(marker);

  // recursively call this function
  // using setTimeout to wait until the JS event loop
  // is idle
  window.setTimeout(addMarker, 0);
};

// start the async processing of the coords
window.setTimeout(addMarker, 0);
```