# Javascript: Show time taken for each function to fun through browser

Tags: javascript, html, optimization, rdfa

This is just a general question, is there a tool/addon for chrome & or firefox to that can either run through each javascript function run on that page and display a result on how long it took to run? or even better yet per line?

The probelm i having is that: i'm creating a visualization tool made through javascript. The user inputs html into a text area and that HTML is further passed into an iframe; as using a third party toolkit for extracting RDFa markup (green turtle) extracts from a HTML document.

Finally, the real issue being if the data inputted has alot of markup then the page simply just crashes. I'm trying to close down which function/code sections are really taking a long time to process to that i can optimize the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea if there is any tool/addon for chrome/firefox for your problem.
But we can do it using some code.
please refer: [How to measure time taken by a function to execute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/313893/how-to-measure-time-taken-by-a-function-to-execute)

Comment: Ah i was considering do that! I'm currently using the google chrome timeline tool. which is rather helpful, but not exactly what i need. Thanks for your suggestion!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the debugging tools on any major browser to do this.

Just press <kbd>F12</kbd> to open 'em up.

Use the Javascript Profiler