# Big O of javascript built-in split function

Tags: javascript, big-o

Example:

```
var string = "abcde";
var array = string.split("");
// array = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
```

What is the amortized running time of this split function? Also, how do I view source code of such built-in functions in javascript?

Comment: Unless the browser is open-source, you can't view the source code.

Comment: It shold be `O(string.length)`.

Comment: Probably something about `O(n*k)` (with `n` the length of the splitted string and `k` some factor that depends somehow on the argument, such as the length or type of the delimiter and the number of results)

Comment: @Bergi Multiplying by a constant doesn't change big O.

Comment: @Barmar: I didn't mean that `k` is a constant.

Comment: I dont think this question has a single answer.  While `string.split` is defined in the [spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.5.4.14), the specific algorithm used can vary by vendor.  However, the spec does spell out the general structure of the algorithm.  Perhaps it's possible to estimate `O(string.split)` based on the spec.

Comment: @Amy While anything is conceivable, this is such a simple operation that there aren't really many realistic choices of implementation.

Answer (score 12):

With an empty delimiter argument, `split` is essentially equivalent to:

```
var len = string.length;
var result = Array(len)
for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    result[i] = string[i];
}
```

This is `O(len)`.

With a delimiter, it becomes `O(string.length * delimiter.length)`, because at each step in the loop it has to test whether there's a match for `delimiter`.

Comment: Is there any documentation, proof or test you can cite for this statement?

Comment: Not that I know of, but there's practically no other reasonable way to implement it

Comment: What language allows finding all the delimiters in a string without searching for them with nested loops? Even if there's a hardware operation to do the string comparison, that's still a loop in the CPU.

Comment: To me, this is `O(n)`.

Comment: Yes, `n == len`

Comment: What makes you think you can't test match for delimiter in better than O(S * delimiter)?

Comment: At each index in the string you have to check whether the following `delimiter.length` characters are equal to `delimiter`.

Comment: That's standard string matching and is already solvable in O(S.length + delimiter.length) using KMP, though Javascript could be using naive algorithm it's wrong to conclude without benchmarking.

Comment: @AbhishekChoudhary that's the complexity of finding a single delimiter. But it has to be done repeatedly to find all the delimiters. See https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-runtime-for-Python-split-built-in-method

Answer (score 0):

It's not very straightforward. The complexity will depend on the delimiter(whether it is a string or a regex). For every iteration, the string is searched for a match on the delimiter. The big O will essentially be O(len * big O of search algorithm) where len is the number of substrings.

Answer (score -4):

**EDIT: The OP did ask "*What is the amortized running time of this split function?*". This is an answer to this precise question**

To get the real running time of a function, see :
[How to measure time taken by a function to execute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/313893/how-to-measure-time-taken-by-a-function-to-execute)

```
var start = new Date().getTime();

for (i = 0; i < 50000; ++i) {
// do something
}

var end = new Date().getTime();
var time = end - start;
alert('Execution time: ' + time);
```

You can't view JS source code, as it's built-in each navigator. You can take a look at [Chromium project](https://chromium.googlesource.com/), maybe you'll find what you are looking for.

I don't know how to get the amortized time of the split, and I dont think you can calculate it without having access to source code.

Comment: Running time is **not** the same thing as Big O.

Comment: To be fair the OP did ask: *"What is running time of this split function?"*. But yes running time doesn't say anything about the Big-O. But this does technically answer the question asked in the body @Amy.