# toDataURL() very slow

Tags: javascript, pdf, canvas

I have a report with charts and tables.
I am using the [html2canvas](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas) with [jsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF) to export this report to PDF file.

But the process is taking a long time, more than 11000ms. 
I've tried to change the format, the quality, but nothing worked.

See below the code I used:

```
html2canvas($('#first-page'), {
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
        firstPage = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 0.5);
    },
    background: '#ffffff'
});
```

I'm doing something wrong or really is a problem?
How I can improve the performance?

Comment: Have you verified that is it actually this step that takes so much time? I’d imagine that rendering your content _onto_ the canvas is gonna take a good amount of time as well ...

Comment: How big is the image?

Comment: @CBroe I did not think about this step, of rendering the html inside the canvas. How can I measure this time?

Comment: @Blindman67 Something like 1170x1400. Is a full page.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/313893/how-to-measure-time-taken-by-a-function-to-execute

Comment: @CBroe You're right, I just measured the time that toDataURL() took, and it was only 28.19482421875ms

Comment: Maybe the problem be the plugin html2canvas, in the step render the content onto the canvas

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to use toDataUrl.http://jsfiddle.net/davidmather/sxp0meer/3/

```
html2canvas($('#first-page'), {
onrendered: function(canvas) {            
    var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'mm');
    doc.addImage(canvas, 'PNG', 10, 10);
    doc.save('sample-file.pdf');
}
});
```

Comment: Nice, I didn't know this.
Unfortunately the problem continues, how @CBroe explained to me, toDataURL() not is the problem, but render the content onto canvas