# How to time different parts of a loop in Javascript

Tags: javascript, optimization, timing

Not a duplicate of [How to measure time taken by a function to execute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/313893/how-to-measure-time-taken-by-a-function-to-execute). Please actually read my question before marking it as a duplicate of something else. Regardless, it's been answered.

---

I have code like

```
for (var i = 0 ; i < 10000 ; i++) {

    doSomething();

    doSomethingElse();

}
```

And I want to know how much time each function inside the loop is taking overall. How do I measure that?

Comment: You can check the used time on devtools Performance tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var t1;
var t2;
var f1Time =0;
var f2Time =0;
for (var i = 0 ; i < 10000 ; i++) {
    t1 = performance.now();
    doSomething();
    t2  = performance.now();
    f1Time+= (t2 - t1);

    t1 = performance.now();
    doSomethingElse();
    t2  = performance.now();
    f1Time+=(t2 - t1);

}
```

Comment: Except that you would use `performance.now()`.

Comment: Yes, that would be more accurate. I updated the answer. Thanks

Comment: That doesn't work. That just gives me the total time taken by the for loop.

Comment: Then you should keep the time inside the loop. Updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

Create a test object and register the individual time differences:

```js
function doSomething() {
  t = Date.now();
  while (Date.now() < t + 13) {}
}

function doSomethingElse() {
  t = Date.now();
  while (Date.now() < t + 27) {}
}
var tests = {
  "doSomething": [],
  "doSomethingElse": []
};
for (var i_1 = 0; i_1 < 10; i_1++) {
  var t = Date.now();
  doSomething();
  tests.doSomething.push(Date.now() - t);
  t = Date.now();
  doSomethingElse();
  tests.doSomethingElse.push(Date.now() - t);
}
for (var key in tests) {
  if (tests.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    tests[key] = tests[key]
      .reduce(function(sum, value) {
        return sum + value;
      }, 0);
  }
}
console.log(tests);
```