# How to time a function in React Native?

Tags: react-native

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/313893/how-to-measure-time-taken-by-a-function-to-execute) suggests using `console.time`, but that isn't available in React Native. Is there a built in way to measure how long a function call takes, without using any third-party packages?

Comment: What version of RN are you using? Because I always use `console.time` and never faced any error whatsoever

Answer (score 24):

Using react-native v0.63+ (not sure about lower versions), you can use the `performance` api, which is described in the question you linked in the original post.

```js
var startTime = performance.now()
    
doSomething()   // <---- measured code goes between startTime and endTime
    
var endTime = performance.now()

console.log(`Call to doSomething took ${endTime - startTime} milliseconds.`)
```

Comment: Do you have a link to the documentation?

Comment: @loekTheDreamer https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/now

Comment: it is still available in 2022, but for some reason using typescript it doesn't recognize it as being available.

Comment: for eslint warning "'performance' is not defined" you need to add `performance: true` into `globals` object in eslint configuration file (for example, .eslintrc.js)

Answer (score 9):

I ran into the same error but managed to fix it easily, just enable debugging on your app to use chrome or react native debugger. From the console of these debuggers, the console.time() and console.timeEnd() is supported and works perfectly

Comment: care to explain the steps, please?

Answer (score 4):

you can use `console.time` but throw third party packages [react-native-console-time-polyfill](https://github.com/MaxGraey/react-native-console-time-polyfill)
otherwise with [performance](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.48/docs/performance.html) monitor from developer menu `Show Perf Monitor`