# Measure process time with Node Js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance

I would like to do the following:

```
console.time("processA");
for(let i; i < 10000; i++) {
// Just to simulate the process
}
console.timeEnd("processA");
```

but I want to capture the time end and use my own logger of information with it.

Is it possible to handle the console output of the timeEnd?

How can I measure the time interval of a process in nodejs?

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/313893/how-to-measure-time-taken-by-a-function-to-execute

Comment: @mb21 thx, in particular I was needing performance in Nodejs, although I did not know about performance.now for browsers and it is a good reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To build upon Deepal's answer using the Node.js performance API, you can also use `performance.mark()`, which allows you to provide named marks at any point of interest in your code.

The following is an example on how creation of instances "Foo" inside of a loop affect the execution of logging.

```js
import { performance } from "perf_hooks";

const INSTANCES = 1000;

class Foo {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
  log() {
    this.message_to_log = 'Logger test: ' + this.name;
  }
}

// Creation of Foo instances inside a foor loop :(
function start() {
  for(let i = 0; i < INSTANCES; i++) {
    const foo = new Foo();
    foo.log();
  }
}

performance.mark("mark_foologger_start");
start();
performance.mark("mark_foologger_end");


// Logging without creation of instances inside for loop
function startImproved(foos) {
  for(let i = 0, length = foos.length; i < length; i++) {
    foos[i].log();
  }
}

const fooInstances = [];
for(let i = 0; i < INSTANCES; i++) {
  fooInstances.push(new Foo(`Logger ${i}`));
}

performance.mark("mark_foologgerimproved_start");
startImproved(fooInstances);
performance.mark("mark_foologgerimproved_end");

console.log('Timeline of the performance get entries');
console.log(performance.getEntries());

console.log('Results on the foo logger duration with creation of new instances inside loop');
console.log(
  performance.measure(
    "measure_foologger_perf",
    "mark_foologger_start",
    "mark_foologger_end"
  )
);

console.log('Results on the foo logger duration without creation of new instances inside loop');
console.log(
  performance.measure(
    "measure_foologger_perf",
    "mark_foologgerimproved_start",
    "mark_foologgerimproved_end"
  )
);
```

The `duration` shows the difference between the two markers in milliseconds.

One advantage of using `performance.mark()` is that these markers are added to the performance timeline, which allows you to retrieve them using [`performance.getEntries()`](https://nodejs.org/api/perf_hooks.html#performancegetentries) or a [`PerformanceObserver`](https://nodejs.org/api/perf_hooks.html#class-performanceobserver).

Here the logs of the time line and the duration of each case:

```bash
Timeline of the performance get entries
[
  PerformanceMark {
    name: 'mark_foologger_start',
    entryType: 'mark',
    startTime: 19.05731000006199,
    duration: 0,
    detail: null
  },
  PerformanceMark {
    name: 'mark_foologger_end',
    entryType: 'mark',
    startTime: 19.334975000470877,
    duration: 0,
    detail: null
  },
  PerformanceMark {
    name: 'mark_foologgerimproved_start',
    entryType: 'mark',
    startTime: 19.490791000425816,
    duration: 0,
    detail: null
  },
  PerformanceMark {
    name: 'mark_foologgerimproved_end',
    entryType: 'mark',
    startTime: 19.587886000052094,
    duration: 0,
    detail: null
  }
]
Results on the foo logger duration with creation of new instances inside loop
PerformanceMeasure {
  name: 'measure_foologger_perf',
  entryType: 'measure',
  startTime: 19.05731000006199,
  duration: 0.27766500040888786
}
Results on the foo logger duration without creation of new instances inside loop
PerformanceMeasure {
  name: 'measure_foologger_perf',
  entryType: 'measure',
  startTime: 19.490791000425816,
  duration: 0.09709499962627888
}
```

Answer (score 20):

Since you are targeting nodejs, you can use `process.hrtime` as stated in the [docs](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/process.html#process_process_hrtime_time)

> The process.hrtime() method returns the current high-resolution real time in a [seconds, nanoseconds] tuple Array, where nanoseconds is the remaining part of the real time that can't be represented in second precision.

So you can measure timings up to nanosecond, something that `console.time` can't, as you can see in your example `console.time` or `Date` difference measures 0s.

For example:

```js
const NS_PER_SEC = 1e9;
const MS_PER_NS = 1e-6
const time = process.hrtime();
for (let i; i < 10000; i++) {
  // Just to simulate the process
}
const diff = process.hrtime(time);
console.log(`Benchmark took ${diff[0] * NS_PER_SEC + diff[1]} nanoseconds`);
console.log(`Benchmark took ${ (diff[0] * NS_PER_SEC + diff[1])  * MS_PER_NS } milliseconds`);
```

Comment: A typescript utility function to get the milliseconds: `const getMsFromHrTime = (diff: ReturnType<HRTime>) => (diff[0] * NS_PER_SEC + diff[1]) * MS_PER_NS;`

Comment: For 2020 people coming across this: use process.hrtime.bigint(). The non bigint version has been made legacy.

Answer (score 12):

Starting from Node v8.5, you can use browser-equivalent `performance.now()` which is easier to use than `process.hrtime` because it outputs the time in milliseconds directly, therefore you don't have to do a conversion as in `process.hrtime`

```js
const { performance } = require("perf_hooks");

const start = performance.now();
doSomething();
const end = performance.now();

console.log(`time taken: ${end - start}ms`);
```

You can find more info from [Node.js Docs on Performance API](https://nodejs.org/api/perf_hooks.html#performancenow).

Answer (score 5):

Since I'm using timers in multiple places, I wrote a simple class based on [Alex's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48770420/1038034):

```
const t = new Timer('For Loop')
// your code
t.runtimeMs()     // => 1212.34
t.runtimeMsStr()  // => 'For Loop took 1232.34 milliseconds'
```

Here's the code:

```js
class Timer {
    // Automatically starts the timer
    constructor(name = 'Benchmark') {
        this.NS_PER_SEC = 1e9;
        this.MS_PER_NS = 1e-6
        this.name = name;
        this.startTime = process.hrtime();
    }

    // returns the time in ms since instantiation
    // can be called multiple times
    runtimeMs() {
        const diff = process.hrtime(this.startTime);
        return (diff[0] * this.NS_PER_SEC + diff[1]) * this.MS_PER_NS;
    }

    // retuns a string: the time in ms since instantiation
    runtimeMsStr() {
        return `${this.name} took ${this.runtimeMs()} milliseconds`;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var startTime = new Date();
for(let i; i < 10000; i++) {
// Just to simulate the process
}
var endTime = new Date() - startTime;
```

You will get the total time that it takes to complete the operation

Comment: May be using momentjs to substract time could be an option
const startTime = moment(Date.now());
//process
const totalTime = moment(Date.now()).substract(startTime);

Answer (score 0):

See here https://alligator.io/js/console-time-timeend/

```js
var begin=console.time('t');

for(let i; i < 100000; i++) {
// Just to simulate the process
}
var end= console.timeEnd('t');

var timeSpent=(end-begin) / 1000 + "secs";
```

Comment: end and begin are undefined, timeSpent is NaNsecs at the end