# JavaScript - Bubble sort vs Cocktail sort speed

Tags: javascript, performance, sorting

I am measuring speed performance of sorting algorithms. Input data is array of numbers in descending order. I assume Cocktail sort should be slighty faster on descending array, but almost every time, it is slower than Bubble sort.

There is my code:

```
function cocktailTP(array)
    {
        const startTime = performance.now();
        let swapped = false;
        let start = 0;
        let end = array.length - 1;
        let temp;

        do {
            swapped = false;
            for (let i = start; i < end; i++) {
                if (array[i] > array[i + 1]) {
                    temp = array[i];
                    array[i] = array[i + 1];
                    array[i + 1] = temp;
                    swapped = true;
                }
            }
            end--;

            for (let j = end; j > start; j--) {
                if (array[j] < array[j - 1]) {
                    temp = array[j];
                    array[j] = array[j - 1];
                    array[j - 1] = temp;
                    swapped = true;
                }
            }
            start++;
        } while (swapped);

        const endTime = performance.now();
        const executionTime = endTime - startTime;
        console.log(`Cocktail sort took ${executionTime} milliseconds to sort an array of ${array.length} elements.`);
    }

    function bubbleSortTP(array)
    {
        const startTime = performance.now();
        for (let i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) 
        { 
            for (let j = 0; j < (array.length - i - 1); j++) 
            { 
                if (array[j] > array[j + 1]) 
                { 
                    const temp = array[j];
                    array[j] = array[j + 1];
                    array[j + 1] = temp;
                } 
            } 
        }
        const endTime = performance.now();
        const executionTime = endTime - startTime;
        console.log(`Bubble sort took ${executionTime} milliseconds to sort an array of ${array.length} elements.`);
    }

    let arr = [];
    const firstCopy = arr.slice();
    const secondCopy = arr.slice();
    cocktailTP(firstCopy);
    bubbleSortTP(secondCopy);
```

I also rewrite that code into C++ and tested it. Cocktail sort was every time faster than Bubble sort. The bigger the input array (descending order), the bigger the time difference between these two algorithms. Unfortunately, I have not been able to replicate this behavior in JavaScript. Is there any particular reason, why is Cockatil sort in JavaScript slower than Bubble sort?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52069915/accurately-measure-a-javascript-function-performance-while-displaying-the-output or similar.

Comment: I don't think I have a problem with time accuracy. The code usually takes thousands of milliseconds, so even if performance.now() is not 100% accurate, few milliseconds should not be problem here.

Comment: eliminate `swapped` and change the do/while to `while (start < end) { ... }`.  That will reduce the number of operations performed inside the loops which may help