# Which one of these ArrayToMap functions usages is better performance-wise?

Tags: javascript, performance, time-complexity

Trying to Map an Array, which one of these implementations is better performance-wise? Is there a better solution?

```
//Given the following Array of people:
const people = [ { name: 'Alice', available: true },  { name: 'Bob', available: false }, { name: 'Charlie', available: true }];

const mapWithReduce = (people) => people.reduce((map, person) => ({ [person.name]: person.available, ...map }), {});

const mapWithForEach = (people) => {
    const map = {};
    people.forEach((person) => map[person.name] = person.available);
    return map;
}
```

I find *mapWithReduce* prettier but I don't know if *...map}* is copying the map every iteration. *mapWithForEach* seems more performant.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to measure time taken by a function to execute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/313893/how-to-measure-time-taken-by-a-function-to-execute)

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy I'm not only looking for numbers but also an explanation of what _...map_ does in the reducer and to look for other implementations

Comment: @J.Nicastro the `...map` object spread syntax is indeed copying the cumulative map every iteration.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Got it! Thanks Patrick!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Performance-wise, using a [`for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) loop is the fastest.

[image: benchmark]

```js
const people = [{ name: 'Alice', available: true }, { name: 'Bob', available: false }, { name: 'Charlie', available: true }]

const mapWithForLoop = (key, value) => array => {
  const map = {}

  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    const entry = array[i]
    map[entry[key]] = entry[value]
  }

  return map
}

const mapPeopleWithForLoop = mapWithForLoop('name', 'available')

console.log(mapPeopleWithForLoop(people))
```

The [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method comes close, though.

Comment: forEach() is it then. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

*I like this solution.*

```js
const people = [ 
  { name: 'Alice', available: true },
  { name: 'Bob', available: false },
  { name: 'Charlie', available: true }
];

const peopleMap = people.reduce((map, person) => {
  map[person.name] = person;
  return map;
}, {});

console.log(peopleMap);
```

**Looks equals than the forEach solution but without creating local vars.**

https://jsperf.com/arraymapeachreduce/9

[image]
[image]

Comment: Good improvement. I would suggest using [this test](https://jsperf.com/arraymapeachreduce/10) though, as declaring the array of `people` should not be considered within the benchmark. All that does is add a constant offset to ops/sec for each case.

Answer (score 1):

they should both be identical if you make their implementations the same and reduce is a little easier to grok because developers know that it has an accumulator whereas in the forEach, you're just sort of implementing reduce yourself

```
const mapWithReduce = (people) => people.reduce((map, person) => 
  {
    map[person.name]: = person.available;
    return map
  }, {}
);
```

edit: it's possible that under the hood `forEach` is more performant, but if you're using babel or another transpiler, it's probably a moot point because at this point, they should do the work of making the more idiomatic version performant. ([source](https://hackernoon.com/javascript-performance-test-for-vs-for-each-vs-map-reduce-filter-find-32c1113f19d7))