# Fastest way to retrieve information from array and display in html

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, performance

I am creating an app in html5 for mobile, and I have all the information of the items inside an array with 887 entries. Each entry have 32 key with values, some with more than one value.

I am using a for loop to iterate the array, and when I find the entry that match the html element it shows the item information with a html block.

I found that it's more efficient to cache the array lenght to use in the for loop. So instead of doing this:

`for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){//code};`

I am doing this which is more fast:

```
var array_len = array.length;
for (var i = 0; i < array_len; i++){//code};
```

Another idea that I tested is creating an index for the array to avoid loops, like this:

```
var index = {
  "strawberry": 0,
  "pear": 1,
  "orange": 2,
  "watermelon": 3,
  "fruit_salad": 4,
  "water": 5,
  "orange_juice": 6,
  "pear_juice": 7,
  "strawberry_juice": 8,
  "watermelon_juice": 9,
  "potato": 10,
  "french_fries": 11
}
```

And then call the item info using a function like this:

```
var singleItem = $('.item');
singleItem.each(function() {
  var item = $(this).attr('class').split(' ')[1];
  var n = index[item];
  var a_items = array[n];
$(this).html(CODE DO DISPLAY THE ITEM INFORMATION HERE)
}
```

So when I use a code like this: `<div class="item watermelon"></div>` it should retrieve the item information without the need to loop through the array.

Below is an example code I wrote to represent the situation, with a short array of items. In the real app, the main array which holds the items information is 887 items long. And I do some for loops inside the other for loop to retrieve informations like `stats` and the `used in` example.

So, it's a for loop inside a for loop.

The question is, there's a more efficient way of doing this?
Because some pages that display one category of items, with aproximatedely 100 items taks 5, 6 seconds to load, and I need it to be more faster.

Edit: Codepen code that shows performance time with both codes:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YBVjKV

```js
// icons: https://www.flaticon.com/search/2?word=food&style_id=28
var array = [
  {
    "name": "strawberry",
    "price": "2.00",
    "type": "fruit",
    "stats": [
      {"type":"hunger","val":"4"},
      {"type":"thirst","val":"2"},
      {"type":"bladder","val":"-2"}
    ],
    "used_in":["strawberry_juice","fruit_salad"],
    "icon": "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/135/135717.png"
  },
  {
    "name": "pear",
    "price": "1.50",
    "type": "fruit",
    "stats": [
      {"type":"hunger","val":"6"},
      {"type":"thirst","val":"4"},
      {"type":"bladder","val":"-2"}
    ],
    "used_in":["pear_juice","fruit_salad"],
    "icon": "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/167/167260.png"
  },
  {
    "name": "orange",
    "price": "0.80",
    "type": "fruit",
    "stats": [
      {"type":"hunger","val":"6"},
      {"type":"thirst","val":"5"},
      {"type":"bladder","val":"-3"}
    ],
    "used_in":["orange_juice","fruit_salad"],
    "icon": "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/415/415734.png"
  },
  {
    "name": "watermelon",
    "price": "5.50",
    "type": "fruit",
    "stats": [
      {"type":"hunger","val":"4"},
      {"type":"thirst","val":"8"},
      {"type":"bladder","val":"-6"}
    ],
    "used_in":["watermelon_juice","fruit_salad"],
    "icon": "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/415/415731.png"
  },
  {
    "name": "fruit_salad",
    "price": "6.50",
    "type": "fruit",
    "stats": [
      {"type":"hunger","val":"10"},
      {"type":"thirst","val":"3"},
      {"type":"bladder","val":"-2"}
    ],
    "ingredients": ["strawberry","pear","orange","watermelon"],
    "icon": "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/415/415744.png"
  },
  {
    "name": "water",
    "price": "1.50",
    "type": "drink",
    "stats": [
      {"type":"thirst","val":"8"},
      {"type":"bladder","val":"-3"}
    ],
    "used_in":["orange_juice","pear_juice","strawberry_juice","watermelon_juice"],
    "icon": "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/135/135662.png"
  },
  {
    "name": "orange_juice",
    "price": "6.50",
    "type": "drink",
    "stats": [
      {"type":"thirst","val":"6"},
      {"type":"bladder","val":"-2"}
    ],
    "ingredients":["orange","water"],
    "icon": "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/167/167612.png"
  },
  {
    "name": "pear_juice",
    "price": "6.50",
    "type": "drink",
    "stats": [
      {"type":"thirst","val":"6"},
      {"type":"bladder","val":"-2"}
    ],
    "ingredients":["pear","water"],
    "icon": "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/167/167623.png"
  },
  {
    "name": "strawberry_juice",
    "price": "6.50",
    "type": "drink",
    "stats": [
      {"type":"thirst","val":"4"},
      {"type":"bladder","val":"-2"}
    ],
    "ingredients":["strawberry","water"],
    "icon": "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/167/167254.png"
  },
  {
    "name": "watermelon_juice",
    "price": "6.50",
    "type": "drink",
    "stats": [
      {"type":"thirst","val":"6"},
      {"type":"bladder","val":"-3"}
    ],
    "ingredients":["watermelon","water"],
    "icon": "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/167/167620.png"
  },
  {
    "name": "potato",
    "price": "1.00",
    "type": "food",
    "stats": [
      {"type":"hunger","val":"4"},
      {"type":"bladder","val":"-2"}
    ],
    "used_in":["french_fries"],
    "icon": "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/135/135676.png"
  },

  {
    "name": "french_fries",
    "price": "3.50",
    "type": "food",
    "stats": [
      {"type":"hunger","val":"10"},
      {"type":"thirst","val":"-4"},
      {"type":"bladder","val":"-2"}
    ],
    "ingredients": ["potato"],
    "icon": "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/135/135589.png"
  }


]

var array_len = array.length;
function gen(){
  var allitems = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < array_len; i++){
    var item = array[i];
    var name = item.name;
    var price = item.price;
    var type = item.type;
    var icon = item.icon;
    allitems += '<div class="item '+name+'"></div>';
  }
  $('.total').html(array_len);
  $('.allitems').html(allitems);
}

function gen2(){
  for (var j = 0; j < array_len; j++){
    var item = array[j];
    var name = item.name;
    var formatted_name = name.replace(/_/g,' ');
    var price = item.price;
    var type = item.type;
    var icon = item.icon;
    var ing = item.ingredients;
    var used_in = item.used_in;
    var stats = item.stats;
    var stats_info = "";
    var ingredients = "";
    var used = "";
    var stat_item = "";
    if(stats != undefined){
      for(var s in stats){
        var stat = stats[s];
        var type = stat.type;
        var val = stat.val
        stat_item += '<div class="stat">'+
          '<i class="'+type+'"></i>'+
          '<span class="stat_val">'+val+'</span>'+
          '</div>'
      }
      stats_info = '<div class="stats_info">'+
        stat_item+
        '</div>';
    }
    for(var i in ing){
      var ing_item = ing[i];
      var format_ing = ing_item.replace(/_/g,' ');
      ingredients += '<div class="ingredient"><i class="'+ing_item+'"></i>'+
        '<span class="ing_txt">'+format_ing+'</span>'+
        '</div>';
    }
    for(var k in used_in){
      var ing_item = used_in[k];
      var format_ing = ing_item.replace(/_/g,' ');
      used += '<div class="ingredient"><i class="'+ing_item+'"></i>'+
        '<span class="ing_txt">'+format_ing+'</span>'+
        '</div>';
    }
    var ing_block = "";
    if(ing != undefined){
      ing_block = '<div class="ingredients_block">'+
        '<div class="ingredient_txt">Uses:</div>'+
        ingredients+
        '</div>';
    }
    if(used_in != undefined){
      ing_block = '<div class="ingredients_block">'+
        '<div class="usedngredient_txt">Used in:</div>'+
        used+
        '</div>';
    }

    $('.item.'+name).html
    ('<div class="items">'+
     '<div class="itemblock">'+
     '<i class="'+name+'"></i>'+
     '<span class="name">'+formatted_name+'</span>'+
     '<span class="price">$ '+price+'</span>'+
     '<span class="type">'+type+'</span>'+
     '</div>'+
     stats_info+
     ing_block+
     '</div>')
  }
}
gen()
gen2()
```

```css
.strawberry{background-image:url(https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/135/135717.png);}
.pear{background-image:url(https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/167/167260.png);}
.orange{background-image:url(https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/415/415734.png);}
.watermelon{background-image:url(https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/415/415731.png);}
.fruit_salad{background-image:url(https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/415/415744.png);}
.water{background-image:url(https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/135/135662.png);}
.orange_juice{background-image:url(https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/167/167612.png);}
.pear_juice{background-image:url(https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/167/167623.png);}
.strawberry_juice{background-image:url(https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/167/167254.png);}
.watermelon_juice{background-image:url(https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/167/167620.png);}
.potato{background-image:url(https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/135/135676.png);}
.french_fries{background-image:url(https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/135/135589.png);}
.hunger {background-image:url(https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/608/608857.png);}
.thirst {background-image:url(https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/135/135662.png);}
.bladder {background-image:url(https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/1402/1402847.png);}

body {
  background-color: #a3d5d3;
  font-family: arial;
}
.totalitems {
  display: block;
  background: #131313;
  color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  text-align: center;
}
.totalitems .total_txt {
  margin: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.allitems {
  display: block;
}
.item {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 2px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-image: none;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 320px;
}
.items {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  background-color: #000;
  padding: 1px;
}
.itemblock {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #333;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  min-height: 40px;
}
.itemblock .items {
  display: block;
  background-color: #333;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}
.itemblock i{
  width: 28px;
  height: 28px;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  align-items: center;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  margin: 2px;
}
.itemblock .name {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0 5px 0 5px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  color: #fff;
  width: 100px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
.itemblock .price {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0 2px;
  color: #ffc107;
  width: 50px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
.itemblock .type {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  margin: 0 15px;
  color: #9E9E9E;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
.stats_info {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #333;
  padding: 8px;
  justify-content: center;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
}
.stats_info .stat {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 50px;
}
.stats_info .stat i {
  display: flex;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.stats_info .stat .stat_val {
  display: flex;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin: 0 5px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  justify-content: center;
}
.ingredients_block {
  display: block;
  background-color: #333;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  min-height: 82px;
}
.ingredients_block .usedngredient_txt,
.ingredients_block .ingredient_txt{
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: left;
}
.ingredients_block .ingredient {
  display: inline-block;
  align-items: center;
  width: 75px;
}
.ingredients_block .ingredient i {
  display: flex;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.ingredients_block .ingredient .ing_txt {
  display: flex;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="totalitems">
  <span class="total_txt">Total items:</span>
  <span class="total"></span>
</div>
<div class="allitems"></div>
<!-- SEE THIS CODE IN FULL PAGE FOR BETTER VISUALIZATION -->
```

Comment: How are you loading the items? Using AJAX or is it just in your JS like your code sample? Perhaps the bottleneck here isn't your algorithm, but how long it takes to retrieve your data. If the wait time perturbs you, then you might want to compromise and load only part of the data at a time, either by putting it in a database or splitting it into separate smaller files that can be loaded individually.

Comment: I have one json file with all the 887 items (1.037 kb). And then I have another file that runs the code to execute the functions.

Comment: That's a whole megabyte worth of data to load on each page. Combine with all the other things your site has to load, including images, css, js, etc., that could easily slow down your site by a lot. I'm not sure if it's 5-6 seconds worth though. Have you done any testing to determine if your actual loading of the data is the problem rather than your display algorithm?

Comment: How can I test if the loading of that file is the problem? I still think it's the for loops. Doing some tests here it looks like using the `var singleItem = $('.item'); singleItem.each(function() { }` it's more fast.

Comment: You can measure `gen` and `gen2` by [timing only the function call](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1975103/8237835). I'd say it's easiest to use [console.time](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/time) and [console.timeEnd](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/timeEnd)

Comment: Nice idea, I saw that `performance.now()` is more efficient to measure functions. I updated the code with this pen that shows the time it took to load both functions

Comment: You should do so on your actual site with the full dataset and report back. Some quick math though: Based on the codepen you provided and my own test, it takes at most 2ms (on my computer) for your algorithm to handle 12 items. If we assume a linear scaling factor then ~1000 items * 2ms / 12 items = .1667 seconds. I'd say use this knowledge and tools to further investigate whether if its your truly your algorithm, the data load time, or the [rendering time](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/rendering-tools). In any case the solution seems to be to segment your data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This a comparison between `filter , map or find`, `for`,`$.each` and `reduce`.
In the code change the `map to filter or find` to see the diffrent.
For `find` the code is here https://jsfiddle.net/ibrth/3awoj1b9/3/

```js
var index = {
  "strawberry": 0,
  "pear": 1,
  "orange": 2,
  "watermelon": 3,
  "fruit_salad": 4,
  "water": 5,
  "orange_juice": 6,
  "pear_juice": 7,
  "strawberry_juice": 8,
  "watermelon_juice": 9,
  "potato": 10,
  "french_fries": 11
}

var array = [
  {
    "name": "strawberry",
    "price": "2.00",
    "type": "fruit",
    "stats": [
      {"type":"hunger","val":"4"},
      {"type":"thirst","val":"2"},
      {"type":"bladder","val":"-2"}
    ],
    "used_in":["strawberry_juice","fruit_salad"],
    "icon": "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/135/135717.png"
  },
  {
    "name": "pear",
    "price": "1.50",
    "type": "fruit",
    "stats": [
      {"type":"hunger","val":"6"},
      {"type":"thirst","val":"4"},
      {"type":"bladder","val":"-2"}
    ],
    "used_in":["pear_juice","fruit_salad"],
    "icon": "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/167/167260.png"
  },
  {
    "name": "orange",
    "price": "0.80",
    "type": "fruit",
    "stats": [
      {"type":"hunger","val":"6"},
      {"type":"thirst","val":"5"},
      {"type":"bladder","val":"-3"}
    ],
    "used_in":["orange_juice","fruit_salad"],
    "icon": "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/415/415734.png"
  },
  {
    "name": "watermelon",
    "price": "5.50",
    "type": "fruit",
    "stats": [
      {"type":"hunger","val":"4"},
      {"type":"thirst","val":"8"},
      {"type":"bladder","val":"-6"}
    ],
    "used_in":["watermelon_juice","fruit_salad"],
    "icon": "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/415/415731.png"
  },
  {
    "name": "fruit_salad",
    "price": "6.50",
    "type": "fruit",
    "stats": [
      {"type":"hunger","val":"10"},
      {"type":"thirst","val":"3"},
      {"type":"bladder","val":"-2"}
    ],
    "ingredients": ["strawberry","pear","orange","watermelon"],
    "icon": "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/415/415744.png"
  },
  {
    "name": "water",
    "price": "1.50",
    "type": "drink",
    "stats": [
      {"type":"thirst","val":"8"},
      {"type":"bladder","val":"-3"}
    ],
    "used_in":["orange_juice","pear_juice","strawberry_juice","watermelon_juice"],
    "icon": "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/135/135662.png"
  },
  {
    "name": "orange_juice",
    "price": "6.50",
    "type": "drink",
    "stats": [
      {"type":"thirst","val":"6"},
      {"type":"bladder","val":"-2"}
    ],
    "ingredients":["orange","water"],
    "icon": "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/167/167612.png"
  },
  {
    "name": "pear_juice",
    "price": "6.50",
    "type": "drink",
    "stats": [
      {"type":"thirst","val":"6"},
      {"type":"bladder","val":"-2"}
    ],
    "ingredients":["pear","water"],
    "icon": "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/167/167623.png"
  },
  {
    "name": "strawberry_juice",
    "price": "6.50",
    "type": "drink",
    "stats": [
      {"type":"thirst","val":"4"},
      {"type":"bladder","val":"-2"}
    ],
    "ingredients":["strawberry","water"],
    "icon": "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/167/167254.png"
  },
  {
    "name": "watermelon_juice",
    "price": "6.50",
    "type": "drink",
    "stats": [
      {"type":"thirst","val":"6"},
      {"type":"bladder","val":"-3"}
    ],
    "ingredients":["watermelon","water"],
    "icon": "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/167/167620.png"
  },

  {
    "name": "french_fries",
    "price": "3.50",
    "type": "food",
    "stats": [
      {"type":"hunger","val":"10"},
      {"type":"thirst","val":"-4"},
      {"type":"bladder","val":"-2"}
    ],
    "ingredients": ["potato"],
    "icon": "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/135/135589.png"
  },

  {
    "name": "french_fries",
    "price": "3.50",
    "type": "food",
    "stats": [
      {"type":"hunger","val":"10"},
      {"type":"thirst","val":"-4"},
      {"type":"bladder","val":"-2"}
    ],
    "ingredients": ["potato"],
    "icon": "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/135/135589.png"
  },

  {
    "name": "french_fries",
    "price": "3.50",
    "type": "food",
    "stats": [
      {"type":"hunger","val":"10"},
      {"type":"thirst","val":"-4"},
      {"type":"bladder","val":"-2"}
    ],
    "ingredients": ["potato"],
    "icon": "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/135/135589.png"
  },

  {
    "name": "french_fries",
    "price": "3.50",
    "type": "food",
    "stats": [
      {"type":"hunger","val":"10"},
      {"type":"thirst","val":"-4"},
      {"type":"bladder","val":"-2"}
    ],
    "ingredients": ["potato"],
    "icon": "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/135/135589.png"
  },

  {
    "name": "french_fries",
    "price": "3.50",
    "type": "food",
    "stats": [
      {"type":"hunger","val":"10"},
      {"type":"thirst","val":"-4"},
      {"type":"bladder","val":"-2"}
    ],
    "ingredients": ["potato"],
    "icon": "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/135/135589.png"
  },

  {
    "name": "french_fries",
    "price": "3.50",
    "type": "food",
    "stats": [
      {"type":"hunger","val":"10"},
      {"type":"thirst","val":"-4"},
      {"type":"bladder","val":"-2"}
    ],
    "ingredients": ["potato"],
    "icon": "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/135/135589.png"
  },

  {
    "name": "french_fries",
    "price": "3.50",
    "type": "food",
    "stats": [
      {"type":"hunger","val":"10"},
      {"type":"thirst","val":"-4"},
      {"type":"bladder","val":"-2"}
    ],
    "ingredients": ["potato"],
    "icon": "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/135/135589.png"
  },

  {
    "name": "french_fries",
    "price": "3.50",
    "type": "food",
    "stats": [
      {"type":"hunger","val":"10"},
      {"type":"thirst","val":"-4"},
      {"type":"bladder","val":"-2"}
    ],
    "ingredients": ["potato"],
    "icon": "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/135/135589.png"
  },

  {
    "name": "french_fries",
    "price": "3.50",
    "type": "food",
    "stats": [
      {"type":"hunger","val":"10"},
      {"type":"thirst","val":"-4"},
      {"type":"bladder","val":"-2"}
    ],
    "ingredients": ["potato"],
    "icon": "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/135/135589.png"
  },

  {
    "name": "french_fries",
    "price": "3.50",
    "type": "food",
    "stats": [
      {"type":"hunger","val":"10"},
      {"type":"thirst","val":"-4"},
      {"type":"bladder","val":"-2"}
    ],
    "ingredients": ["potato"],
    "icon": "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/135/135589.png"
  },

  {
    "name": "french_fries",
    "price": "3.50",
    "type": "food",
    "stats": [
      {"type":"hunger","val":"10"},
      {"type":"thirst","val":"-4"},
      {"type":"bladder","val":"-2"}
    ],
    "ingredients": ["potato"],
    "icon": "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/135/135589.png"
  },

  {
    "name": "french_fries",
    "price": "3.50",
    "type": "food",
    "stats": [
      {"type":"hunger","val":"10"},
      {"type":"thirst","val":"-4"},
      {"type":"bladder","val":"-2"}
    ],
    "ingredients": ["potato"],
    "icon": "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/135/135589.png"
  }
]

var array_len = array.length;
// Function used to create the index of the items

//createindex();

function gen(){
  var allitems = "";
  array.reduce((i, item) =>{
 
    var name = item.name;
    var price = item.price;
    var type = item.type;
    var icon = item.icon;
    allitems += '<div class="item '+name+'"></div>'
  });
  $('.total').html(array_len);
  $('.allitems').html(allitems);
}

var currentDates = array.filter(function(obj) {
  return obj;
});

function gen2(){
  array.reduce((j, item) =>{

    var name = item.name;
    var formatted_name = name.replace(/_/g,' ');
    var price = item.price;
    var type = item.type;
    var icon = item.icon;
    var ing = item.ingredients;
    var used_in = item.used_in;
    var stats = item.stats;
    var stats_info = "";
    var ingredients = "";
    var used = "";
    var stat_item = "";
    if(stats != undefined){
      for(var s in stats){
        var stat = stats[s];
        var type = stat.type;
        var val = stat.val
        stat_item += '<div class="stat">'+
          '<i class="'+type+'"></i>'+
          '<span class="stat_val">'+val+'</span>'+
          '</div>'
      }
      stats_info = '<div class="stats_info">'+
        stat_item+
        '</div>';
    }
    for(var i in ing){
      var ing_item = ing[i];
      var format_ing = ing_item.replace(/_/g,' ');
      ingredients += '<div class="ingredient"><i class="'+ing_item+'"></i>'+
        '<span class="ing_txt">'+format_ing+'</span>'+
        '</div>';
    }
    for(var k in used_in){
      var ing_item = used_in[k];
      var format_ing = ing_item.replace(/_/g,' ');
      used += '<div class="ingredient"><i class="'+ing_item+'"></i>'+
        '<span class="ing_txt">'+format_ing+'</span>'+
        '</div>';
    }
    var ing_block = "";
    if(ing != undefined){
      ing_block = '<div class="ingredients_block">'+
        '<div class="ingredient_txt">Uses:</div>'+
        ingredients+
        '</div>';
    }
    if(used_in != undefined){
      ing_block = '<div class="ingredients_block">'+
        '<div class="usedngredient_txt">Used in:</div>'+
        used+
        '</div>';
    }

    $('.allitems .item.'+name).html
    ('<div class="items">'+
     '<div class="itemblock">'+
     '<i class="'+name+'"></i>'+
     '<span class="name">'+formatted_name+'</span>'+
     '<span class="price">$ '+price+'</span>'+
     '<span class="type">'+type+'</span>'+
     '</div>'+
     stats_info+
     ing_block+
     '</div>')
  });
}


function gen3(){
  var allitems = "";
  array.reduce((i, item) =>{
 
    var name = item.name;
    var price = item.price;
    var type = item.type;
    var icon = item.icon;
    allitems += '<div class="item '+name+'"></div>'
  });
  $('.total').html(array_len);
  $('.allitems').html(allitems);
}



function gen4(){
  array.reduce((j, item) =>{

    var name = item.name;
    var formatted_name = name.replace(/_/g,' ');
    var price = item.price;
    var type = item.type;
    var icon = item.icon;
    var ing = item.ingredients;
    var used_in = item.used_in;
    var stats = item.stats;
    var stats_info = "";
    var ingredients = "";
    var used = "";
    var stat_item = "";
    if(stats != undefined){
      for(var s in stats){
        var stat = stats[s];
        var type = stat.type;
        var val = stat.val
        stat_item += '<div class="stat">'+
          '<i class="'+type+'"></i>'+
          '<span class="stat_val">'+val+'</span>'+
          '</div>'
      }
      stats_info = '<div class="stats_info">'+
        stat_item+
        '</div>';
    }
    for(var i in ing){
      var ing_item = ing[i];
      var format_ing = ing_item.replace(/_/g,' ');
      ingredients += '<div class="ingredient"><i class="'+ing_item+'"></i>'+
        '<span class="ing_txt">'+format_ing+'</span>'+
        '</div>';
    }
    for(var k in used_in){
      var ing_item = used_in[k];
      var format_ing = ing_item.replace(/_/g,' ');
      used += '<div class="ingredient"><i class="'+ing_item+'"></i>'+
        '<span class="ing_txt">'+format_ing+'</span>'+
        '</div>';
    }
    var ing_block = "";
    if(ing != undefined){
      ing_block = '<div class="ingredients_block">'+
        '<div class="ingredient_txt">Uses:</div>'+
        ingredients+
        '</div>';
    }
    if(used_in != undefined){
      ing_block = '<div class="ingredients_block">'+
        '<div class="usedngredient_txt">Used in:</div>'+
        used+
        '</div>';
    }

    $('.allitems .item.'+name).html
    ('<div class="items">'+
     '<div class="itemblock">'+
     '<i class="'+name+'"></i>'+
     '<span class="name">'+formatted_name+'</span>'+
     '<span class="price">$ '+price+'</span>'+
     '<span class="type">'+type+'</span>'+
     '</div>'+
     stats_info+
     ing_block+
     '</div>')
  });
}

function gen6(){
  var allitems = "";
  array.map(( item) =>{
 
    var name = item.name;
    var price = item.price;
    var type = item.type;
    var icon = item.icon;
    allitems += '<div class="item '+name+'"></div>'
  });
  $('.total').html(array_len);
  $('.allitems').html(allitems);
}

var currentDates = array.filter(function(obj) {
  return obj;
});

function gen7(){
  array.map(( item) =>{

    var name = item.name;
    var formatted_name = name.replace(/_/g,' ');
    var price = item.price;
    var type = item.type;
    var icon = item.icon;
    var ing = item.ingredients;
    var used_in = item.used_in;
    var stats = item.stats;
    var stats_info = "";
    var ingredients = "";
    var used = "";
    var stat_item = "";
    if(stats != undefined){
      for(var s in stats){
        var stat = stats[s];
        var type = stat.type;
        var val = stat.val
        stat_item += '<div class="stat">'+
          '<i class="'+type+'"></i>'+
          '<span class="stat_val">'+val+'</span>'+
          '</div>'
      }
      stats_info = '<div class="stats_info">'+
        stat_item+
        '</div>';
    }
    for(var i in ing){
      var ing_item = ing[i];
      var format_ing = ing_item.replace(/_/g,' ');
      ingredients += '<div class="ingredient"><i class="'+ing_item+'"></i>'+
        '<span class="ing_txt">'+format_ing+'</span>'+
        '</div>';
    }
    for(var k in used_in){
      var ing_item = used_in[k];
      var format_ing = ing_item.replace(/_/g,' ');
      used += '<div class="ingredient"><i class="'+ing_item+'"></i>'+
        '<span class="ing_txt">'+format_ing+'</span>'+
        '</div>';
    }
    var ing_block = "";
    if(ing != undefined){
      ing_block = '<div class="ingredients_block">'+
        '<div class="ingredient_txt">Uses:</div>'+
        ingredients+
        '</div>';
    }
    if(used_in != undefined){
      ing_block = '<div class="ingredients_block">'+
        '<div class="usedngredient_txt">Used in:</div>'+
        used+
        '</div>';
    }

    $('.allitems .item.'+name).html
    ('<div class="items">'+
     '<div class="itemblock">'+
     '<i class="'+name+'"></i>'+
     '<span class="name">'+formatted_name+'</span>'+
     '<span class="price">$ '+price+'</span>'+
     '<span class="type">'+type+'</span>'+
     '</div>'+
     stats_info+
     ing_block+
     '</div>')
  });
}


function gen8(){
  var allitems = "";
  
 

// This is a function of current date, so will be empty at some point.


$.each(array, function(i, item) {
   var name = item.name;
    var price = item.price;
    var type = item.type;
    var icon = item.icon;
    allitems += '<div class="item '+name+'"></div>';
});

 

  $('.total').html(array_len);
  $('.allitems').html(allitems);
}

function gen9(){
  $.each(array, function(j, item) {
   
    var name = item.name;
    var formatted_name = name.replace(/_/g,' ');
    var price = item.price;
    var type = item.type;
    var icon = item.icon;
    var ing = item.ingredients;
    var used_in = item.used_in;
    var stats = item.stats;
    var stats_info = "";
    var ingredients = "";
    var used = "";
    var stat_item = "";
    if(stats != undefined){
      for(var s in stats){
        var stat = stats[s];
        var type = stat.type;
        var val = stat.val
        stat_item += '<div class="stat">'+
          '<i class="'+type+'"></i>'+
          '<span class="stat_val">'+val+'</span>'+
          '</div>'
      }
      stats_info = '<div class="stats_info">'+
        stat_item+
        '</div>';
    }
    for(var i in ing){
      var ing_item = ing[i];
      var format_ing = ing_item.replace(/_/g,' ');
      ingredients += '<div class="ingredient"><i class="'+ing_item+'"></i>'+
        '<span class="ing_txt">'+format_ing+'</span>'+
        '</div>';
    }
    for(var k in used_in){
      var ing_item = used_in[k];
      var format_ing = ing_item.replace(/_/g,' ');
      used += '<div class="ingredient"><i class="'+ing_item+'"></i>'+
        '<span class="ing_txt">'+format_ing+'</span>'+
        '</div>';
    }
    var ing_block = "";
    if(ing != undefined){
      ing_block = '<div class="ingredients_block">'+
        '<div class="ingredient_txt">Uses:</div>'+
        ingredients+
        '</div>';
    }
    if(used_in != undefined){
      ing_block = '<div class="ingredients_block">'+
        '<div class="usedngredient_txt">Used in:</div>'+
        used+
        '</div>';
    }

    $('.item.'+name).html
    ('<div class="items">'+
     '<div class="itemblock">'+
     '<i class="'+name+'"></i>'+
     '<span class="name">'+formatted_name+'</span>'+
     '<span class="price">$ '+price+'</span>'+
     '<span class="type">'+type+'</span>'+
     '</div>'+
     stats_info+
     ing_block+
     '</div>')
  });
}

var t0 = performance.now();
$('.allitems').each(function() {
  gen();
  gen2()
});
var t1 = performance.now();
var milliseconds = (t1 - t0);
var seconds = (milliseconds / 1000).toFixed(6);
var method = "Using  reduce  ";
$('.function_time_1').html("Using reduce " + seconds + " seconds.")
console.log("%c "+method+" took " + seconds + " seconds.", 'background: #000; color: #89ff00');

var t2 = performance.now();
$('.individual_items').each(function() {
  gen8();
  gen9()
});

var t3 = performance.now();
var milliseconds2 = (t3 - t2);
var seconds2 = (milliseconds2 / 1000).toFixed(6);
var method = "Using each without looping";
$('.function_time_2').html("Using each without looping took " + seconds2 + " seconds.");
console.log("%c "+method+" took " + seconds2 + " seconds.", 'background: #000; color: #89ff00');


var t4 = performance.now();
$('.allitems').each(function() {
  gen3();
  gen4()
});
var t5 = performance.now();
var milliseconds4 = (t5 - t4);
 var seconds4 = (milliseconds4 / 1000).toFixed(6);
var method5 = "Using for loops ";
$('.function_time_3').html("Using for loops   " + seconds4 + " seconds.")
console.log("%c "+method5+" took " + seconds4 + " seconds.", 'background: #000; color: #89ff00');


 t4 = performance.now();
$('.allitems').each(function() {
  gen6();
  gen7()
});
 t5 = performance.now();
 milliseconds4 = (t5 - t4);
  seconds4 = (milliseconds4 / 1000).toFixed(6);
 method5 = "Using filter ";
$('.function_time_4').html("Using filter   " + seconds4 + " seconds.")
console.log("%c "+method5+" took " + seconds4 + " seconds.", 'background: #000; color: #89ff00');
```

```css
.strawberry{background-image:url(https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/135/135717.png);}
.pear{background-image:url(https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/167/167260.png);}
.orange{background-image:url(https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/415/415734.png);}
.watermelon{background-image:url(https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/415/415731.png);}
.fruit_salad{background-image:url(https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/415/415744.png);}
.water{background-image:url(https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/135/135662.png);}
.orange_juice{background-image:url(https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/167/167612.png);}
.pear_juice{background-image:url(https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/167/167623.png);}
.strawberry_juice{background-image:url(https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/167/167254.png);}
.watermelon_juice{background-image:url(https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/167/167620.png);}
.potato{background-image:url(https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/135/135676.png);}
.french_fries{background-image:url(https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/135/135589.png);}
.hunger {background-image:url(https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/608/608857.png);}
.thirst {background-image:url(https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/135/135662.png);}
.bladder {background-image:url(https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/1402/1402847.png);}

body {
  background-color: #a3d5d3;
  font-family: arial;
}
.debug {
  background-color: #000;
  font-family: consolas;
  color: #ffed00;
  font-size: 13px;
}
.debug div {
  padding: 5px;
}
.totalitems {
  display: block;
  background: #131313;
  color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  text-align: center;
}
.totalitems .total_txt {
  margin: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.allitems {
  display: block;
}
.item {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 2px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-image: none;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 320px;
}
.items {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  background-color: #000;
  padding: 1px;
}
.itemblock {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #333;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  min-height: 40px;
}
.itemblock .items {
  display: block;
  background-color: #333;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}
.itemblock i{
  width: 28px;
  height: 28px;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  align-items: center;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  margin: 2px;
}
.itemblock .name {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0 5px 0 5px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  color: #fff;
  width: 100px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
.itemblock .price {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0 2px;
  color: #ffc107;
  width: 50px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
.itemblock .type {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  margin: 0 15px;
  color: #9E9E9E;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
.stats_info {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #333;
  padding: 8px;
  justify-content: center;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
}
.stats_info .stat {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 50px;
}
.stats_info .stat i {
  display: flex;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.stats_info .stat .stat_val {
  display: flex;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin: 0 5px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  justify-content: center;
}
.ingredients_block {
  display: block;
  background-color: #333;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  min-height: 82px;
}
.ingredients_block .usedngredient_txt,
.ingredients_block .ingredient_txt{
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: left;
}
.ingredients_block .ingredient {
  display: inline-block;
  align-items: center;
  width: 75px;
}
.ingredients_block .ingredient i {
  display: flex;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.ingredients_block .ingredient .ing_txt {
  display: flex;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="debug">
  <div class="function_time_1"></div>
  <div class="function_time_2"></div>
  <div class="function_time_3"></div>
  <div class="function_time_4"></div>
</div>

<div class="totalitems">
  <span class="total_txt">Total items:</span>
  <span class="total"></span>
</div>
<div class="allitems"></div>

<div class="individual_items">
  <div class="item strawberry"></div>
  <div class="item pear"></div>
  <div class="item orange"></div>
  <div class="item watermelon"></div>
  <div class="item fruit_salad"></div>
  <div class="item water"></div>
  <div class="item orange_juice"></div>
  <div class="item pear_juice"></div>
  <div class="item strawberry_juice"></div>
  <div class="item watermelon_juice"></div>
  <div class="item potato"></div>
  <div class="item french_fries"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey I created a pen in codepen testing this and measuring performance, it looks like each still more fast: `https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bzWKxv` take a look please.

Comment: @RogerHN Nice, what about using array.filter.

Comment: @RogerHN  See this: https://flaviocopes.com/javascript-loops-map-filter-reduce-find/

Comment: Using array.filter where? The pen above test the both codes, the first using array.filter like your code, and the second using the `each` like the example code.

Comment: @RogerHN filter or map seems to be the best.

Comment: Really nice, do you know how to use the `find()` method? I saw that it doesn't iterate the array and only returns one value, do you think it's possible to implement that in my code?

Comment: @RogerHN yes change `map` to `find`