# Track time taken from redux action to reducer

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-redux

I need to track the time it takes from the time an action is dispatched from my react component until the action is fulfilled via redux middleware like saga to redux. And I need this as something like reusable so that we can capture and push to a logging system. Any idea of how to accomplish this?

Comment: there are many ways to do it. did you check redux tool? https://github.com/AvraamMavridis/redux-perf-middleware Also did you see the answer for this question https://stackoverflow.com/a/1975103/3305456 ?

Comment: @moshe I checked the redux perf .. that writes to console I am looking for something which I can have as a variable and that I can send as a payload to a service which can write to a log file the other one I guess is advanced nodejs we are using 8.10 node js