# JavaScript promise resolve duration

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

what is the correct way to calculate the duration of a promise?

```
const startTm = Date.now();
p1(params).then(
    (o)=> {
        Log.debug(startTm);
        Log.debug(JSON.stringify(o));
        return o;
    });
const runTm = Date.now() - startTm;
```

The startTm  is invisible inside then().

UPDATE:

my bad. startTm is visible. So is there any other ways?

```
 const startTm = Date.now();

 p1(params).then((o)=> {
    output = o
    console.log(startTm);
    Log.debug(JSON.stringify(o));
    let runTm = Date.now() - startTm;
    Log.debug('duration: ' + runTm + 'ms');
    return o;
});
```

Comment: startTm should not be invisible in the then

Comment: "The startTm is invisible inside then()." — [No, it isn't](https://jsbin.com/wazavoteve/1/edit?js,console)

Comment: after then the promise has been resolved so you should log the start time before and in the then it's the end of your promise

Comment: You'll want to do the calculation of `runTm` inside the `then` handler, btw.

Comment: There is a nice answer here, using performance.now()
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/313893/how-to-measure-time-taken-by-a-function-to-execute

Comment: Thanks folks, I updated my post.

Comment: What is your question then?

Comment: Just for completion, there's a library for this: https://github.com/sindresorhus/p-time . Take a look at the source code. It's quite simple how he does it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to ensure that the duration calculation happens after all prior promises are resolved, which in your case would mean calculating `runTm` after your `Log.debug()` statements, or creating a new `then()` block like so:

```js
/* Mocking p1 to demonstrate technique */
function p1() {
  return new Promise(r => setTimeout(() => r('I took 2 seconds to resolve'), 2000));
}
/* Mock params data */
const params = {};

/* Record start time */
const startTm = Date.now();

p1(params).then((o) => {
    console.log(startTm);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(o));
    return o;
})
.then((o) => {

    /* Calculate duration and log it */
    const runTm = Date.now() - startTm;
    console.log(`Duration was: ${runTm}ms`);

    /* Pass result "o" through */
    return o;
})
```

Answer (score 3):

All what you need:

```js
const p1 = () => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(() => { resolve() }, 2000))

const test = async () => {
  const startTm = Date.now();
  const result = await p1();
  const runTm = Date.now() - startTm;
  console.log(runTm);
}

test();
```

In const 'result' you get result promise as you get it in 'then' callback.

Without async/awaut:

```
const startTm = Date.now();
p1(params).then((result)=> {
  Log.debug(startTm);
  Log.debug(JSON.stringify(result));
  const runTm = Date.now() - startTm; // only available here
  return o;
});
```

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to include how that works differently from the code in the OP.

Comment: Also it does not do anything. (the first one)

Comment: @JonasWilms  I expanded my example.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let p1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
  setTimeout(function(){    
    resolve('pass');
  }, 3000);
});

let runTm;
const startTm = Date.now();

p1.then(
    (o)=> {          
        runTm = Date.now() - startTm;
        console.log(runTm)
        return o;
});
```