# API response time in response header

Tags: javascript, api, http, curl, httpresponse

We are trying to understand total time taken for an api to respond. Currently we are calculating that using a timer. We could't find any header in http response object helpful for this. Meanwhile curl is able to provide the informations like time_namelookup, time_connect, time_appconnect, time_pretransfer, time_redirect, time_redirect, time_starttransfer and time_total.

Is there a way to understand these in javascript/php?

Answer (score 0):

Can you check this [How to measure time taken by a function to execute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/313893/how-to-measure-time-taken-by-a-function-to-execute) you can try calling your api inside that function?