# How to calculate the time spent when using got?

Tags: javascript, node.js, time, xmlhttprequest, node.js-got

Example code:

```
const got = require('got');
async function timeSpent (){
   const time = new Date().getTime()
   await got('***')
   return new Date().getTime() - time
}
```

I wonder if there is a better way?

Comment: You can find alternatives here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/313893/how-to-measure-time-taken-by-a-function-to-execute

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not required to implement your own timing logic when using `got`.

The response includes a timings object that collects all millis spent per phase.

You only need to read out `timings.phases.total` from the response object.

```
const path = "http://localhost:3000/authenticate";
const response = await got.post(path, {
  body: { username: "john_doe", password: "mypass" },
  json: true,
  headers: {
    Accept: "application/json",
    "Content-type": "application/json",
  },
});

logger.debug({type: 'performance', path, duration: response.timings.phases.total});
```

Reference:

https://github.com/sindresorhus/got#timings

https://github.com/sindresorhus/got/pull/590

Answer (score 3):

You may use a 3rd Party [statman-stopwatch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/statman-stopwatch) to easily record the total time.

Example

```
const got = require('got');
const Stopwatch = require('statman-stopwatch');
async function timeSpent (){
    const sw = new Stopwatch();
    sw.start();
    await got('***');
    sw.stop();
    const delta = sw.read();
  return delta;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can go through this way.

```js
console.time('test1');
console.time('test2');

setTimeout( (elem) => {
   console.log('You want to write something here!!');
   console.timeEnd('test2');
}, 2000);

console.timeEnd('test1');
```

Answer (score 1):

**performance** - is a native way to measure things like this.

```
const got = require('got');
async function timeSpent (){
  var t0 = performance.now();
  await got('***')
  var t1 = performance.now();
  console.log("Call to do something took " + (t1 - t0) + " milliseconds.");
  return t1 - t0;
}
```

Check browser support https://caniuse.com/#search=performance

Answer (score 1):

```
 let currentDate = moment().format('YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm')
            let dataCalca = moment(dataValue).format('YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm')
            let hours = moment
              .duration(moment(currentDate, 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm')
                .diff(moment(dataCalca, 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm'))
              ).asHours();
```

So you get the numbers as an hour. You can calculate with that