# Why is difference between date() is NaN?

Tags: javascript

```
    <script>
        var start;
        function shapeAppear() {
            document.getElementById("shapes").style.display = "block";
            var start = new Date().getTime();           

        }
        function delay() {
            setTimeout(shapeAppear,Math.random() *2000);
        }
        delay();

    document.getElementById("shapes").onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById("shapes").style.display = "none";   
    var position = Math.floor(Math.random() * 500);
    document.getElementById("shapes").style.left = position + "px";
    document.getElementById("shapes").style.right = position + "px";
    document.getElementById("shapes").style.top = position + "px";
    document.getElementById("shapes").style.bottom = position + "px";
    var end = new Date().getTime();
    var time =  end - start;
    time /= 1000;
    document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = time + "s";
    delay();
}   
    </script>
```

Here in this code i want the `date()` function to return a specific integer value.
Because when we subtract the two `Date()` functions we must get the integer value.

Comment: Honestly, I don't understand your question, but it looks like you're trying to calculate the time required to do some operation... if this is your use case, I'd take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/313893/how-to-measure-time-taken-by-a-function-to-execute

Comment: Looks to me like start is used before it is set.

Comment: You never assign a value to the `start` variable declared on line one. Only to the `start` variable declared on line 4, which uses `var` so is a **different** variable which is assigned a value that is never read because it immediately drops out of scope.

Answer (score 3):

It is a scoping issue. if you use `var` inside a `function`, that variable will only exist in the scope of that function.

So what you could do is this:

```
var start;

function shapeAppear() {
    start = new Date().getTime();
}
```

By removing `var` in the `shapeAppear` function, you're updating the `var` that is created outside the function.

Besides that as [Rodney](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2216148/rodney) mentioned you call `delay` before `shapeAppear` which means that `start` is not defined when calling `delay`.

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Yeah but also shapeAppear isn't called until after start is used, so start is still used before it is set.

Comment: In this case it should be _"...that variable will **also** exist in the scope of that function..."_. Both `start` variables exist but the inner "masks" the outer one