# Measure API response time with fetch in node.js

Tags: node.js, performance-testing, fetch-api

One of the functions in my node.js app is calling an external API using the fetch function. 
I am trying to find the most accurate way to measure the response time for the said API.

i am using the "Date" method to do it:

```
     let start_time = new Date().getTime();
      fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1')
  .then((res) => {
    return res.json();
  })
.then((data) => {
  console.log('Response time:', new Date().getTime() - start_time);
```

Is there a better\more accurate way to do it with fetch?

Comment: You can refer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/313893/how-to-measure-time-taken-by-a-function-to-execute)

Answer (score 8):

You can use console.time & console.timeEnd as:

```
    console.time("timer1");
      fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1')
  .then((res) => {
    return res.json();
  })
.then((data) => {
  console.timeEnd("timer1");
```

It will print the time elapsed like

```
timer1: 0.105ms
```

Answer (score 2):

In case you want to get the number as variable but not printing it out

```js
    const start = Date.now();
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const secSpent = (Date.now() - start) / 1000; // <---
```