# Calculate total execution time of a function

Tags: javascript

```
const {performance} = require('perf_hooks');
let startTime = performance.now();
const extractedData = await readFunction()
let endTime = performance.now();
let timeTaken = endTime-startTime
```

I want to calculate time taken to execute **readFunction()**. Is this good approach to calculate total time taken to execute **readFunction**? Also on console.log(startTime) it gives some value instead of starting from 0.

So to get precise value should I do the following step or above step is enough to get precise time in milisecond.

```
const {performance} = require('perf_hooks');
let startTime = 0
const extractedData = await readFunction()
let endTime = performance.now();
let timeTaken = endTime-startTime
```

Is timeTaken value in milisecond?  If anyone needs any further information please let me know.

Comment: Have you read up on what `performance.now()` returns? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/now Also, subtracting `0` from any value is the same as using the value itself. So `endTime - startTime` where `startTime === 0` is the same as `endTime`.

Comment: What's the difference between the first and second snippet?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to measure time taken by a function to execute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/313893/how-to-measure-time-taken-by-a-function-to-execute)

Comment: @FelixKling in first snippet on console.log(startTime) gives value say, 1325, where as in second snippte console.log(startTime) will be from .

Answer (score 0):

```
function calculateTime(yourFunction) {
  console.time();
  yourFunction();
  return console.timeEnd();
}
```

```
async function calculateTimeForPromises(yourPromise) {
  console.time();
  await yourPromise();
  return console.timeEnd();
}
```

Is that helpful?