# Reading 100MB file, line by line with Node.js is a lot slower than reading it with C++. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: node.js, performance

I would like to read the extracted version of this Debian package file (http://ftp.debian.org/debian/dists/stable/main/binary-amd64/Packages.xz) with ~10⁶ lines to find out what version a certain package has. I am trying to do that with Node.js but it takes ~2,5s on my machine to find a package with this algorithm:

```js
import { createReadStream } from 'fs';
import readline from 'readline';

async function probeExtractedPackage(
  extractedFile,
  packageName
) {
  const requiredPackageKeys = ['Package', 'Version', 'Homepage'];
  const CHUNK_SIZE = 10000000; // 10MB
  const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: createReadStream(extractedFile, { highWaterMark: CHUNK_SIZE }),
    terminal:false
  });
  let pd = {};
  for await (const line of rl) {
    if (line === '') {
      // now we should have all information available
      if (pd.Package === packageName) {
        return { releases: [{ version: pd.Version }], homepage: pd.Homepage };
      }
      pd = {};
      continue;
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < requiredPackageKeys.length; i++) {
      if (line.startsWith(requiredPackageKeys[i])) {
        pd[requiredPackageKeys[i]] = line
          .substring(requiredPackageKeys[i].length + 1)
          .trim();
        break;
      }
    }
  }

  return null;
}
```

Basically, you can see that I'm reading the file line by line using Node.js' `readline.createInterface`.

In C++, however, the same task takes on the same machine ~300ms with this algorithm:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <chrono>
#include <csignal>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>

std::string getValue(const std::string &line, const std::string &key)
{
  return line.substr(key.size());
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

  std::ifstream infile("/workspace/thefile.txt");
  std::string line;
  std::string packageName;
  std::string packageVersion;
  std::size_t count                     = 0;
  auto container                        = std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string>();
  std::vector<std::string> interestedIn = {"Package:", "Homepage:", "Version:"};

  while(std::getline(infile, line)) {
    count++;
    if(line == "") {
      container = std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string>();
      continue;
    }

    for(const auto &ii : interestedIn) {
      if(line.starts_with(ii)) {
        container[ii] = getValue(line, ii);
        break;
      }
    }
  }

  auto end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
  std::cout << "Took: " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end - start).count() << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Inspected " << count << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

I understand that C++ is more efficient in many aspects, but does this translate to an improvement of a factor 10? I'm more guessing that I'm doing something wrong in Node.js (I just started with it). I'm using Node.js 16.

Comment: You should measure which part of code in node.js takes more time. https://stackoverflow.com/a/1975103/4688321

Comment: One magnitude order between C++ and NodeJS is not really a surprise...

Comment: In the C++ code, instead of `container = ...` why not `container.clear()`?