# Calculate DomContentLoaded

Tags: puppeteer, domcontentloaded

I want to be ensure about the equation of DomContentLoaded time in seconds?

This equation can help me ?

DomContentLoaded = performanceTiming.domContentLoadedEventEnd - performanceTiming.navigationStart

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

[How to measure time taken by a function to execute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/313893/how-to-measure-time-taken-by-a-function-to-execute)

Check this in regards to measuring the time your functions take

In your function that you want to measure the performance of, use the node built in time checkers

```
function doPuppeteerStuff = () => {
  console.time('puppeteer');
  
  //doPuppeteerMagic()
  
  console.timeEnd('puppeteer');
  // Prints: puppeteer: 225.438ms
}
```

https://nodejs.org/api/console.html#console_console_timeend_label
Here is the documentation for it

Comment: Just I want to ensure if I use the right equation

Comment: Oh. Yeah. That's the correct equaton.

timeTaken = timeEnd - timeStart :)

Comment: not performanceTiming.domContentLoadedEventEnd - performanceTiming.navigationStart?

Comment: performanceTiming.domContentLoadedEventEnd - performanceTiming.navigationStart 
Is correct, but it is legacy code. You must try not to use it...

What you can however do is in the function that you are trying to measure the performance of, have the console.time and console.timeEnd helpers

I'm going to edit my answer

Comment: So it is not give me the accurate values?

Comment: It should give accurate values, but this is very old code to use and is not recommended.
Come look here for help on a better way of using this:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceTiming/domContentLoadedEventEnd

Comment: If i use timeEnd - timeStart it is not give a correct answer

Comment: Obvious... because it isn't a real thing you can use... I just made an example...
Communication barrier man...