# Compare execution time of 2 different code snippets

Tags: javascript

Lets say I have 2 different code snippets that do the same thing, and I want to measure which one of those took more time to execute. Example:

```js
function log(text) {
    console.log(text);
}

log("Hello World");
```

and

```js
console.log("Hello World");
```

is there a measurable difference between those 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search about benchmarks, look that with your code: https://jsbench.me/6ol6b8gv88/1

Or here https://jsben.ch/JKZto

Or you can take a look in this question [How to measure time taken by a function to execute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/313893/how-to-measure-time-taken-by-a-function-to-execute?noredirect=1&lq=1)