# how to write a if statement for fetch('link'). So that when one fetch('link1') takes more than 3 second to respond then use the other fetch('link2')

Tags: javascript, html, function, api, rest

How to write an if statement for fetch('link'). So that when one fetch('link1') takes more than 3 seconds to respond then, timeout the link1  use the other fetch('link2')

```
if ()
      {
        fetch('https://api.apilayer.com/exchangerates_data/latest?base=USD', requestOptions)

        .then(response => response.json())
        .catch(error => {
            console.log('Error', error);
        });
      
      return false;
      } else 
      {
        fetch("https://api.apilayer.com/fixer/latest?base=USD", requestOptions)

        .then(response => response.json())
        .catch(error => {
            console.log('Error', error);
        });
      
      return false;
      }
```

I have tried the above code but doesn't work..

Comment: `setTimeout('#result',3000)` is not how [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout) works -

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use something similar to the answer submitted to this question on how to measure the time taken to execute a function and use it for comparison within the conditional, *e.g. (timeTaken > 3000)*

[How to measure time taken by a function to execute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/313893/how-to-measure-time-taken-by-a-function-to-execute)

Hope this helps to steer you in the right direction