# Can't get download event duration using timing method

Tags: javascript, playwright

As mentioned in the title, I am trying to measure how much time a downloading event takes.

I have referred to the documentation: https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-request#request-timing
to write the following lines of code.

```
const downloadPromise = page.waitForEvent("download", { timeout: 35000 });
await page.getByRole("button", { name: "Download" }).click({ timeout: 35000 });
const download = await downloadPromise;
```

The download object is correctly created but I cant find the timing method which from my understanding own the duration of the downloading.

Is there an other way to get the duration of a download using Playwright?

Comment: Please be aware that Java != JavaScript, so your tagging with [tag:playwright-java] was not appropriate.

Comment: Seems like you can use any other [performance measurement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/313893/how-to-measure-time-taken-by-a-function-to-execute) in JS, right?